# How to update message before it's delivered

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, msmq

I am queuing a bunch of messages, and the queue eventually delivers the messages as records into a `sql server` database. I need to update the message to display the `datetime` at which the message is going to be delivered. As I am thinking about this, my request does not sound logical; however, is there a way or is there an event to which I can subscribe to get the `datetime` right before the message is delivered?

```
var msgQ = new MessageQueue(_myque);
msgTx.Begin();
msgQ.Send(message, msgTx);
msgTx.Commit();
```

Please note that I am unable to make any changes to the database, and would need to solve this through .NET code.

Comment: Is `DateTime.Now` not sufficient to call when the message is popped off the queue?  Is the delivery datetime supposed to be a property of the message, or something that is used once the message is received by the receiver?

Comment: That's my question. How do I capture the popping off

Comment: So - is the question how to receive messages from an MSMQ?  If not, then please show the code that does the receiving.

Comment: Yes that is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following sample will push a message onto a message queue, and then receive it after a small delay:

First, a message to send:

```
public class Order
{
    public int orderId;
    public DateTime orderDate;
    public DateTime receivedDate;
};
```

Send the a new `Order`, wait a little, and then receive it from the queue:

```
// a private queue - set to applicable queue path.
var myQueue = new MessageQueue(".\\private$\\myQueue");

myQueue.Send(new Order { orderId = 1, orderDate = DateTime.Now});

// a 10 second delay to demonstrate an infrastructure 
// delay between the send and receive   
Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

var message = myQueue.Receive();

var receivedOrder = (Order)message.Body;
receivedOrder.receivedDate = DateTime.Now;  

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Order {0} sent at {1}, received at {2}", receivedOrder.orderId, receivedOrder.orderDate, receivedOrder.receivedDate));
```